# Looking for an ActiveX Component capable of rendering PNG’s transparency and translucency

Tags: c++, com, png, activex, dataflex

I need a component or some way to render PNGs on my application in order to improve its design. I believe somewhere some control should exist, but I did not find it.
I am developing on Visual Dataflex, and all I can use is Windows' API and COM-based components.I do not have GDI+, which makes use of C++ classes.
If no free solution is to be found, I will build some component on C++, but there should be a way to do this easier and more successfully.

Has someone a suggestion?

Forgive my english.
Kind Regards.

Claudio M. Souza Junior.

Developer.

Comment: You have a dev tool called "Visual" that cannot display bitmaps?

Comment: Ironically, it's so. It builds Win32 applications, calls every windows' api, but do not render pngs unless through COM Components. I do not have access to the window procedure, and this dificults processing WM_PAINT on my own, but it is not impossible to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/) site has a full list of implementation:

[Programming Libraries and Toolkits with PNG Support](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngaptk.html)

This one looks interesting (open source, win32 support): http://www.paintlib.de/paintlib/ (untested). It's not maitained anymore but source is included, and there are not many reason to face big issues today if it used to work well during many years.

It's not COM-based, but is it a problem for you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Does it renders translucency and transparency?